# Solr 4.5 get documents with geospatial search into a range of distance

Tags: solr, geospatial, solr4

is it possible to get the documents with geospatial search into a range of distance?
I want to get all my documents that have a distance more then 10km and less then 100km.

For example somethings like this: &fq={!geofilt}&sfield=coordinate&**d=[10 TO 100]**&pt=40,18

Please, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr Distance Filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867113/solr-distance-filtering)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
&fq={!frange l=0.08 u=0.89 key='Between 10 to 100'}{!geofilt score=distance sfield=coordinate pt=40,18 d=100}
```

Range values should be in degrees. (used Kms to degrees conversion)